# Storing session cookie in android.webkit.CookieManager

Tags: android, cookies, webview, android-volley

I use the Volley library for performing my app's requests. Now I really need to perform some operations following this order:

- A POST request using Volley library
- I receive a 204 response with a session cookie
- I need to set that cookie to be used with WebViews

I need to perform the first request with Volley because the response has a header containing the uri for the next request. Than I need to capture that header.

The problem is that I can not save the session cookie using the `CookieManager`, because, as the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#setCookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says: "The cookie being set must not have expired and must not be a session cookie, otherwise it will be ignored.".

Is there a way to store that cookie for later uses with WebViews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely enough, the documentation is either out of date or outright incorrect, it seems that the `CookieManager` will save session cookies with no problems at all. ([Here's the bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67475))

This snippet works for me:

```
private void syncCookie(String domain, Cookie sessionCookie) {
    CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    String cookieString = sessionCookie.getName() + "=" + sessionCookie.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionCookie.getDomain();
    cookieManager.setCookie(domain, cookieString);
    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
}
```

Comment: You are right. Doc is outdated! I have seen that cookies are stored correctly! Many thanks