# save php cookie on android application

Tags: php, android, node.js, cookies

I am new in android i just want to know did there are way to save cookie in android

after login

so when he send some request after login i cant recognize if he login or not .. another think i want to know it can I get that cookie value from android in node.js when send request to nodeJs by socket ?

Comment: I don't think you can. Consider using localStorage instead.

Comment: It's possible, you can save/get cookies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25781951/storing-session-cookie-in-android-webkit-cookiemanager

Comment: @Doug so how facebook and another application work ?

Comment: @alexmike You can use shared preferences or SQLite database

Comment: Stateless apps, google jwt and I'm fairly sure you'll find facebook use oauth

Comment: This question is missing any information about what you have tried so far and what your server application/API looks like and how it behaves.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharedPreferences or a local database to store the login information. Even better would be to implement a custom Account type for your application. The Account Manager does provide you with functions to store login tokens on the device and check if you are logged in or not. Anyways: You will have to create these checks yourself. Check the return code on an API request or have an API endpoint that just returns the login status.